# Как отправить несколько медиафайлов списку людей - телеграмм

Tags: telegram, aiogram, бот

Столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу отправить несколько файлов пользователям из списка ботом в телеграмме:

```
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, types
...
async def main():
    for i in range(len(database)):
        await bot.send_media_group(database[i][0], media)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Ругается на функцию `asyncio.run(main())` и в логах выводит только:

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x000001C917E68820>
Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x000001C917E701C0>, 593529.531)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x000001C917E68730>
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x000001C917E68520>
```

Если отправлять просто текст, `bot.send_message`, то бот отправляет всем сообщение, но все равно ругается на незакрытую сессию.

Comment: Там же написано, что проблема в том, что `media` закрыт, нужен код, где вы его инициализируете, так ничего не понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Без полного кода не совсем понятно в чем может быть проблема.

Но можно предположить, что вы завершаете работу, прежде чем файлы успевают полностью отправиться. То что получалось с сообщениями только подтверждает эту версию. Сообщения отправляются быстро и ваш код успевал их корректно отправить и потом завершиться.

А сейчас у вас похоже идет завершение сессии до того как файлы отправились. Как это поправить - либо не использовать ассинхрронный вызов, либо использовать различные механизмы типа семафоров и мьютексов, чтобы подождать завершения процесса отправки и только потом завершить работу.